# Freeze caused by bluetooth and webcam

Tags: bluetooth, webcam, crash

My web app has a webcam running using ng-camera(based on webcam.js), and a separate bluetooth sniffer running on node js on the background. After several minutes running, the app and raspberry pi will always freeze completely. When checking the kern.log it says "**Bluetooth: hci0 : Frame reassembly failed (-84)**" many times.

Does anyone know what probably causes this and how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by having an external Bluetooth dongle and disable the internal one. I don't know why and how but it's working perfectly without freezing now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Yeah, please accept the answer, as your problem's been solved. It is actually popping up again and again.